# PHP Permissions System

Tags: php, permissions, user-management

It may sound a bit weird, but in Bukkit (Minecraft Server) there's a permissions managment that works like that for example:

`pluginname.class.function`

Now i can give a user or group the permission to call let's say the function "create":

`pluginname.class.create`

or to all functions of a class:

`pluginname.class.*`

or even for all classes:

`pluginname.*`

Does anyone know a system that works like this for PHP? I googled but i found absolutely nothing.
So I'm basically looking for a User/Group permissions managment system that also allows me to specify some kind of wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called Access Control Lists. Google has plenty of results for both plugins and classes.

Also might be worth looking at:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370371/recommend-a-php-acl-class

Answer (score 1):

[`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) supports this kind of thing but you need to write all the wireing yourself - eg. you can jsut install it and havit work automagically.